# How to retrieve the available free on-disk swap memory size in Java programmatically

Tags: java, memory

I have tried to get the free (on-disk) swap size programmatically in Java 8 on Windows in the following way (see getFreeSwapMemoryInMB()), all metrics seem correct except the free swap memory (on-disk):

```
public class ApplicationRuntime {

    private static final OperatingSystemMXBean OS  
         = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

    public static long getTotalVirtualMemory() {
         return OS.getTotalSwapSpaceSize(); // OS.getTotalSwapSpaceSize() actually returns the total **virtual** memory (RAM + on-disk)
    }

    public static long getFreeVirtualMemory() {
        return OS.getFreeSwapSpaceSize(); // OS.getFreeSwapSpaceSize() actually returns the total free **virtual** memory (RAM + on-disk)
    }

    public static long getFreePhysicalMemory() {
        return OS.getFreePhysicalMemorySize();
    }

    public static long getTotalPhysicalMemory() {
        return OS.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
    }

    public static long getTotalSwapMemory() { // total on-disk virtual memory
        return getTotalVirtualMemory() - getTotalPhysicalMemory(); // CORRECT (according to Windows settings)
    }

    public static long getFreeSwapMemory() { // free on-disk virtual memory
        return getFreeVirtualMemory() - getFreePhysicalMemory(); // INCORRECT seems to return way less than the actual value (many GB less than the Windows performance monitor suggests, on 32GB of total on-disk swap)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get a reliable metric for the free on-disk swap size? Now the metric is lower than expected based on the Windows Performance Monitor suggests (using %used page file). Is this a known issue with OperatingSystemMXBean?
The terminology used: Virtual memory = Physical Memory (RAM) + Swap Memory (on-disk).
Thanks.